# Can't post through the REST API: Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user

Tags: wordpress, api, rest

So I've created a fresh instance od Wordpress.

Added a user and created Application password.

I am trying to post anything through the postman with:

> POST domain.name/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/

And in the request body a json:

```
{
    "status": "draft",
    "title": "TEST",
    "content": "TEST CONTENT"
}
```

But everytime I get:

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_create",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

I haver tried to change the user role from administrator to creator or editor. Nothing helps.

When I call /wp-json I get post as allowed method. What I am doing wrong?